# Regular expression to capture only the first timestamp per line

Tags: regex

Given I have a text file which looks like this:

```
2018-11-19T16:28:04.315+0000: 10.686: [GC (System.gc()) 2018-11-19T16:28:04.336+0000: 10.707: [SoftReference overflow: false
AdaptiveSizeStart: 10.709 collection: 2
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 2
[PSYoungGen: 127597K->19813K(1223168K)] 127701K->19925K(4019712K), 0.0245152 secs] 
2018-11-19T16:28:04.339+0000: 10.710: [Full GC (System.gc()) 2018-11-19T16:28:04.354+0000: 10.725: [SoftReference 10.768 collection: 3
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 3
[PSYoungGen: 19813K->0K(1223168K)] [ParOldGen: 112K->18999K(2796544K)] 19925K->18999K(4019712K)
2018-11-19T16:28:09.964+0000: 16.335: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-11-19T16:28:09.980+0000: 16.351: [SoftReference false
AdaptiveSizeStart: 16.366 collection: 4
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 4
[PSYoungGen: 1041736K->67361K(1223168K)] 1060735K->86376K(4019712K), 0.0314594 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs]
```

Some lines contain timestamps and of those lines, the timestamp is repeated several times on those lines.

**I would like to use a regular expression to get the first match per line.**

I've got this so far:

```
((-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))
```

And it produces matches like this `2018-11-19T16:28:04` (which is great) but how do I restrict it to only stop at the first match per line?

(for example, on line 1 of my example, it would match for the two timestamps when I want it to stop after the first)

Comment: Have you tried by prefix the whole regex with '^'?

Comment: Prepend  an anchor `^` https://regex101.com/r/kwtq9U/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is just fine, maybe  with an start anchor might work OK:

```
^((-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/VYnJ5L/1/)

or

```
^.*?((-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/Vxc5gy/1/)

As a minor point other than that, we can also simplify it to, if `\d` would be OK:

```
^((-?(?:[1-9]\d*)?\d{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01]\d):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d))
```

#### [DEMO 3](https://regex101.com/r/u7Y63m/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VYnJ5L/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/VYnJ5L/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Never heard of jex.im - very handy website, thank you. I see that the `^` would only capture a timestamp if the line starts with a timestamp. How would you capture the first timestamp in a line if the line starts with something other than a timestamp?

Comment: so if I've understood you, what  `^.*?` really means is starting from the start of the line (as denoted by `^`), match all characters (as denoted by `.`), and treat each char as part of one big match instead of treating each char as an individual match (as denoted by `*`) but then what does the `?` mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend the anchor `^` to your regex so that it is bound to the start of line. Some like:

```
^((-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))
```